# CTAD and designated initializers in C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer, ctad

I have already stated confusion about CTAD with designated initializers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886451/c20-designated-initializers-with-templated-types), but i have another confusion with a very similar code snippet

```cpp
template <typename int_t=int, typename float_t=float>
struct my_pair {
    int_t   first;
    float_t second;
};

template<typename ... ts>
my_pair(ts...) -> my_pair<ts...>;

int main() {
    my_pair x{.second = 20.f};
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x.first), int> ); //FAILS <- its deduced to float
    static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x.second), float> );
}
```

It seems like the deduction guide causes the type of `first` to be deduced to `float`, even though i do not give an explicit `.first` in the designated initializer. The deduction guide apparently only cares about the order in the initializer, no matter the keyword (`.second`). Should the deduction guide be smart about this or should there be a "designated deduction guide"?

See the example on https://godbolt.org/z/cm6Yi7

Comment: The deduction guide does muddle the water a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57886451/2069064) as a starting point. We have the same initial three candidates:

```
template <class T=int, class U=float>
struct my_pair {
    T first;
    U second;
};

// default constructor
template <class T=int, class U=float>
auto __f() -> my_pair<T, U>;

// copy candidate
template <class T=int, class U=float>
auto __f(my_pair<T, U>) -> my_pair<T, U>;

// deduction guide
template <class... T>
auto __f(T...) -> my_pair<T...>;
```

And the aggregate deduction candidate is based on the actual *initializer-list* or *designated-initializer-list* we provide, not the actual underlying members of the aggregate. Our *designated-initializer-list* is `{.second = 20.f}` so our aggregate deduction candidate becomes:

```
// aggregate deduction candidate
template <class T=int, class U=float>
auto __f(U) -> my_pair<T, U>;
```

The template parameters always come from the primary class template, so we bring in the default template arguments from there. The candidate arguments come from the *initializer-list*, and the type of `second` is `U`.

The aggregate deduction candidate is the best candidate (only the aggregate deduction candidate and the deduction guide are viable, the aggregate deduction candidate is more specialized), so we end up with `my_pair<int, float>`.

---

Having finished CTAD, we now start over and effectively do

```
my_pair<int, float> x{.second = 20.f};
```

Which works, and leads to `x.first` being initialized from `{}`.

---

CTAD for aggregates was only adopted very recently (at the Cologne meeting in July 2019, two months ago). Before that feature, this would still have been well-formed:

```
my_pair{.second = 20.f};
```

Why? We don't yet have the aggregate deduction candidate, but we still do have the deduction guide... which *is* viable. It gives us `my_pair<float>`. Which is to say, `my_pair<float, float>` once you fill in the default template argument for `U`.

That's why gcc is giving you the behavior you see - it simply does not yet implement CTAD for aggregates, and is giving you the old behavior.

Comment: but i end up with `my_pair<float, float>`. according to your answer (and my logical thinking), i shouldn't..

Comment: So, to address the question in the post. `first` being deduced as `float` is a compiler bug.

Comment: @kawillzocken Added an update to explain why you end up with `my_pair<float, float>`. It's not a compiler bug, it's a compiler-hasn't-yet-implemented-this-feature.

Comment: Well, GCC 9.1, Clang 9, and VS 2019 16.1 all implemented CTAD and designated initializer, and none implemented CTAD for aggregates. But only GCC deduces first as float. So at least one compiler is buggy. And GCC has a record of ignoring designators.